# How can i use deep-clone using my method for arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, clone, deep-copy

I have the following code.

```
class Animal : ICloneable
{
    int age;
    string name;

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public Animal Clone()
    {
        return (Animal)((ICloneable)this).Clone();
    }
}


class ZOO:ICloneable
{
    int capacity;
    List<Animal> list = new List<Animal>();

    Animal[] animals;

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public ZOO Clone()
    {
        ZOO nnew = (ZOO)((ICloneable)this).Clone();
        List<Animal> copy = new List<Animal>();
        foreach(Animal a in list)
        {
            copy.Add(a.Clone());
        }
        nnew.list = copy;

        return nnew;

    }
}
```

How can i use the method ZOO Clone() for my array of animals?
It worked with list, but i can't figure out how to do that using
Animal[] animals for cloning.
P.S: The list is an example. I only need to clone using the array.

Comment: `var copy = list.Select(a => a.Clone()).ToArray()`

Comment: And without using the list?

Comment: C'mon, `var copy = animals.Select(a => a.Clone()).ToArray()`